# I want to convert from Point to Agent that gives me proper location

Tags: anylogic

I am working on agent-based modelling where I have created a function that generates a random point inside a region and then converts that point to agent. However, when I use this function later, the points don't give me a proper location on the map for further computation. I want to know what I am doing wrong? Or how can this be improved.

The return type for the function is ArrayList

```
ArrayList<DeliveryHouse> House = new ArrayList<DeliveryHouse>();
int i;
Point p;
DeliveryHouse h;
 for(i=0;i<packagesC2C;i++)
   {
    p = main.Region2.randomPointInside();
    h = main.deliveryHouse.setLocation(p);
    House.add(i, h);
   };
return House;
```

Comment: not clear what you mean. Your Points are defined only locally within the function, they cannot be accessed later. Only what you return, i.e. your DeliveryHouses agents. Each of those has a location you can access using myHouse.getX(), or getXYZ() or getLocation().

Answer (score 0):

The major problem I see with your code is that you are not initializing the agent "h" but pointing it to one agent you have at main which means you keep changing its location in the loop and it will only reflect the last location. The array list you created will have multiple references to same agent instead of one agent per location.

If you want to create an agent per location you need to create an agent population called "deliveryHouses" of the agent type "DeliveryHouse" and change your code to the following. Note that the population will have all the agents so you do not need any output from the function.

```
int i;
Point p;
for(i=0;i<packagesC2C;i++)
   {
    DeliveryHouse h = main.add_deliveryHouses();
    p = main.Region2.randomPointInside();
    h.setLocation(p);
   }
```